# Is it possible to have an alias for sys.stdout in python?

Tags: python

Consider this sample python code. It reads from stdin and writes to a file.

```
import sys

arg1 = sys.argv[1]

f = open(arg1,'w')
f.write('<html><head><title></title></head><body>')

for line in sys.stdin:
    f.write("<p>")
    f.write(line)
    f.write("</p>")

f.write("</body></html>")
f.close()
```

Suppose I want to modify this same program to write to stdout instead. Then, I'll have to replace each instance of `f.write()` with `sys.stdout.write()`. But that would be too tedious. I want to know if there is a way to specify `f` as an alias for `sys.stdout`, so that `f.write()` is treated as `sys.stdout.write()`.

Comment: How about `f = sys.stdout`?

Comment: @AdamRosenfield, if that works, then please make it an answer! I am a Python newbie.

Comment: @CodeBlue you tell us

Comment: Also, don't forget the `print >> f, ...` syntax

Comment: @Eric That works only on python2 and, personally, I never liked it, nor I've seen it used in big projects. @CodeBlue note that `sys.stdout` is an instance of the `file` type like any file you open via `open`; it isn't special in any way. E.g. `sys.stdout = open('output', 'w')` will redirect standard output to the file `output`.

Comment: @Bakuriu: Python 3 has `print(..., file=f)`, which is good too

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just do

```
>>> import sys
>>> f = sys.stdout
>>> f.write('abc')
abc
```

Now you just need to do `f = sys.stdout` instead of `f = open(fileName)`. (And remove `f.close()`)

**Also**, Please consider using the following syntax for files.

```
with open(fileName, 'r') as f:
    # Do Something
```

The file automatically gets closed for you this way.

Answer (score 15):

Names in Python are just bindings. Therefore:

```
f = sys.stdout
```

Just binds the name `f` to *the object* that's *also bound* to `sys.stdout`...

Note that since they're both the same object, any changes you make to `f` or `sys.stdout` at this point will affect *both*... So don't do `f.close()` as you normally wouldn't want to do `sys.stdout.close()`...

Comment: you can also do the (much) more sketchy `sys.stdout = open('some_file.txt','w');`

Answer (score 3):

Yes, in python, you can alias every class / function / method etc. Just assign the value you want to use to another variable:

```
import sys
f = sys.stdout
```

Now every method you call on `f` will get called on `sys.stdout`. You can do this with whatever you like, for example also with `i = sys.stdin` etc.

Comment: Except not `in = sys.stdin`, because `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: @Eric: sorry, forgot about `in` being a keyword

Answer (score 0):

This is properly the job of a shell anyway; just send it to standard out and redirect it to a file using `>filename` when you invoke the script.